# JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList() returns an empty array

Tags: java, linux, networking, network-programming, jpcap

I'm new to Jpcap. I'm using

```
NetworkInterface[] arr=JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
System.out.println(arr.length);
```

to get the devices from Jpcap. But it returns an empty array. When I print the length of the array, it is 0. I' using ubuntu 11.10 and installed libpcap using `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev`. I have jpcap.jar in my classpath. I don't understand why I'm not getting any Network Devices. Can someone help me.

EDIT:
When I run `ifconfig` in terminal I get this output.

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:a9:05:cb:8d:fb
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>             Interrupt:17
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:758 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:758 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:27296 (27.2 KB)  TX bytes:27296 (27.2 KB)
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:c6:14:6c:68
>             inet addr:192.168.2.55  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::226:c6ff:fe14:6c68/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:11385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:6088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:4582447 (4.5 MB)  TX bytes:1203113 (1.2 MB)

Comment: Have you tried: `String[] devices = PacketCapture.lookupDevices();`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem when I run in Ubuntu 11.10 and netbeans. When I try to run the jar file using the terminal (with sudo permissions) it worked. I think the issue is with permissions in linux.

Running the .jar file in the terminal `sudo java -jar YourJarFile.jar` would solve he issue.

Comment: in my case I ran it as root,  +1 for pointing to the permissions issue